# Remove Magento default js in custom theme

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

In custom theme which I want to apply to some page, I don't want to include magento default Js.
Based on this docs - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css_remove

so like for example I am trying to remove 'storage.js','storage-manager.js','query-builder.js' etc.
as per the instructions -

> that if a static asset is added with a module path (for example
>   Magento_Catalog::js/sample.js) in the initial layout, you need to
>   specify the module path as well when removing the asset.

but the files I referred above are included, I am unable to locate. what I should include in remove src like

```
<remove src="storage.js" />
```

The full path on inspection shows

```
https://mysite/pub/static/frontend/Iaz/iaz_home/en_US/Magento_Catalog/js/product/query-builder.js
```

Looking for a suitable solution.

Comment: You have try this link :- https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Programming/How-to-remove-js-files/td-p/48294

Comment: when search for these files - it is not included in any xml files, that is the issue. but for example I am looking for `query-builder.js'` it is included in another file `data-storage.js` with this code `define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'ko',
    'mageUtils',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/product/query-builder',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
],`

Comment: you are try this code :- <remove src="Magento_Catalog::js/compare.js" />

Comment: Looking for the same solution as well.